# Toggle Wifi On/Off using MobileWifi private framework

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, wifi

For a private project using the iPhone SDK (not for the app store), I would like to toggle wifi on & off. I've done something similar for Bluetooth, but can't find the required information for Wifi. I assume I need to use the MobileWifi framework. Can anyone give some directions and/or code? Most likely I expect I need a header file for the MobileWifi framework as well.

Note once again, this is not for the app store, as Apple will not allow apps that use private frameworks such as this.

Comment: Looking for something same, you solved it??

Comment: Please Check out the link below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303981/ios6-1-problems-while-trying-to-access-wifi-rssi-mobilewifi-framework

Answer (score 2):

Apple is not exposing any public APIs for WiFi. You might not be able to do that.